# Plugin or shortcode for ISBN number?

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, plugins

I have a Woocommerce site with a catalogue of books.  Each book has an ISBN (or EAN) number entered in a custom field.

I need to do two things with the ISBN, and I don't want to have to manually enter code for each product:

1. I need to link to the Google books preview (at the moment I do this manually by adding another custom field with this script (only the ISBN changes from product to product)

   `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://books.google.com/books/previewlib.js"
   </script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   GBS_insertPreviewButtonPopup('ISBN:978-1-920590-37-6');
   </script>`
2. I need to link to the products for sale via a number of other online shops, with my affiliate ID followed by the ISBN number, for example

   `http://etrader.kalahari.net/referral.asp?linkid=5&partnerid=5710&ISBN=978-1-920590-37-6`

Can anyone tell me whether I need to create a plugin or use shortcode to achieve this?

Comment: I'd say shortcode is the way to go. Where you put it doesn't matter - either place it in your `functions.php` file or write a plugin that provides the shortcode. To get you started: [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I'm a bit our of my depth, as I've never created a function...Yikes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had some help from a developer, and would like to share the solution:

```
function get_google_tag( $isbn_metadata ) {
return (
    /* '<span class="post-meta-key">Preview: </span>' . */
    '<script type="text/javascript" src="http://books.google.com/books/previewlib.js"></script>' .
    '<script type="text/javascript">' .
    'GBS_insertPreviewButtonPopup(\'ISBN:' . $isbn_metadata . '\');' .
    '</script>'
);
}
```